# Shell Script - Find length of an array passed as parameter to a function

Tags: arrays, shell

I am trying to access my array passed as parameter to my function inside my shell script. I am able to process individual element of the array but when I try to find length of the array, it only shows 1. My script is:

```
ar=(8 2 3 4 5 6 7)

test() {

    sum=0
    ref=$1[@]
    echo ${#ref[@]}

    for i in ${!ref}
    do
        sum=`expr $sum + $i`
    done
    echo "sum is: $sum"
}

test ar
```

If I do

```
echo ${#ref}
```

it gives me 5 as result. Dont know the reason for this result as well.

Is there any way I can find a way out of this ?

Comment: That's not how argument passing in bash works. Or variables.

Comment: Can you help me out then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ts () {
  set $1[*]
  ref=(${!1})
  echo ${#ref[*]}
  for i in ${ref[*]}
  do
    (( sm += i ))
  done
  echo sum is: $sm
}
ar=(8 2 3 4 5 6 7)
ts ar
```

Output

```
7
sum is: 35
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven...  It's working fine. Please answer Tim's queries. I also want to know that...  :) . Thanks.